# ordenar y filtrar datos con R

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo una base de datos con 3 variables,código,fecha y precipitaciones

El codigo pertenece a una ubicacion geografica,
la fecha esta en dias
y precipitaciones esta en mm

debo calcular la suma anual(porque esta en dias) de las precipitaciones para cada codigo, ademas debo hacer lo mismo para octubre del año t-1 a mayo del año t para cada codigo.

```
EXP_DATOS read.csv2<-("C:/Users/Desktop/EXP_DATOS.txt",na.strings=c("","NA"), sep="")
View(EXP_DATOS)
attach(EXP_DATOS)
library(magicfor)
precipitaciones=as.numeric(precip)
fecha= transform(fecha, x = as.Date(as.character(fecha), "%d%m%Y"))
c=c(cod)
f=seq(as.Date("1969/1/1"), as.Date("2018/12/31"),by="day",length.out = NULL)
for (i in c) {
  t=subset(EXP_DATOS, cod==i) 
    for (r in f) {
          
          sum(precipitaciones)
        }
}

magic_result_as_dataframe()
```

estaba pensando en algo como esto pero no se como seguir.
Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

acá va una posibilidad creando la nueva variable temporada, usando los paquetes "lubridate" y "dplyr". Seguro hay otras formas de hacerlo, pero esta es la que se me ocurrió para trabajar por temporadas:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

#creo un df con datos como el que tienes tú, no incluyo localización geografica 
df <- data.frame(fecha=seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "day", length.out = 365*4),
             precip = rnorm(365*4,mean=3,sd=0.5))

#Extraigo año y mes a partir de la fecha
df <- df %>% mutate(anio=year(fecha)) %>%
       mutate(mes=month(fecha)) 

#Otra forma de sumar precipitación por año
df.anual <- df %>%
  group_by(anio) %>% 
  summarise(precip.anual = sum(precip))

#Filtra solo los meses de interes
new.df <- df %>% filter(mes %in% c(1:5, 10:12))

#Crear la variable temporada que pone juntos en una misma temporada
#los meses de oct. nov. y dic del año t-1 y enero a mayo del año t. 
#Cuando los meses son oct, nov, dic los "pasa" a la temporada siguiente. 
#La temporada de lluvia queda codificada como el año t+1.
#Es decir la temporada de lluvia 2002 corresponde a 2001/1002: oct, nov, dic del 
#2001 más enero a mayo del 2002. 
new.df$temporada <- ifelse(new.df$mes>9, new.df$anio+1, new.df$anio)

#Agrupas por temporada y sumas
new.df %>% group_by(temporada) %>% summarise(precip.por.temp = sum(precip))
```

Y obtienes la suma de prec. por temporada

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  temporada precip.por.temp
  <dbl>           <dbl>
1      2000            460.
2      2001            730.
3      2002            727.
4      2003            717.
5      2004            265.
```